# How to solve tractrix equation for x?

Tags: problem-solving

Tractrix curve is defined by the following equation:

$y= asech^{-1}(x/a)-sqrt(a^2-x^2)$

where ***a*** is a constant.

I would like to apply this equation for an algorithm where ***y*** is a known value. Is it possible to solve it for x?

Comment: I think you will need a numerical method.

Comment: If someone visits this question in the future: [inverse of $x-\tanh(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3524850/inverse-of-x-tanhx/4415669#4415669)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to fully solve it, but I'll share what I've got so far:
$$y = a{sech}^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{x}{a}\Bigr)-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$$
Since ${sech}^{-1}(x) = {cosh}^{-1}\bigl(\frac{1}{x}\bigr)$:
$$y = a{cosh}^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{a}{x}\Bigr)-\sqrt{a^2-x^2} \\ 
\sqrt{a^2-x^2} = a{cosh}^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{a}{x}\Bigr)-y \\ 
a^2-x^2 = a^2\biggr({cosh}^{-1}\Bigr(\frac{a}{x}\Bigl)\biggl)^2 + y^2 -2a{cosh}^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{a}{x}\Bigr)y$$
With the substitution of ${cosh}^{-1}\bigr(\frac{a}{x}\bigl) := w$ and $\frac{a}{cosh(w)} = x$ we get:
$$a^2 - \frac{a^2}{cosh^{2}(w)} = a^2w^2 + y^2 + 2awy \\ 
0 = a^2w^2 + 2awy + \frac{a^2}{cosh^{2}(w)} - a^2 + y^2$$
I'll use the quadratic formula for $w$:
$$w_{1,2} = \frac{-2ay \pm \sqrt{4a^2y^2-4a^2\Bigl(\frac{a^2}{{cosh}^{2}(w)}-a^2+y^2\Bigr)}}{2a^2}$$
We can fortunately simplify with $2$ and $a$:
$$w_{1,2} = \frac{-y \pm \sqrt{ay^2-a\Bigl(\frac{a^2}{{cosh}^{2}(w)}-a^2+y^2\Bigr)}}{a} \\ 
w_{1,2} = \frac{-y \pm \sqrt{a^2\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{{cosh^{2}(w)}}\Bigr)}}{a} \\ 
w_{1,2} = \frac{-y \pm \sqrt{a^2({tanh}^{2}(w))}}{a} \\ 
w_{1,2} = \frac{-y \pm atanh(w)}{a}$$
$$aw \mp atanh(w) = -y$$ 
$$w \pm tanh(w) = -\frac{y}{a}$$
From here I wasn't able to continue, however we can deduce the following and approximate $x$:
$$\lim_{w \to \infty}(w \pm tanh(w)) = w \pm 1$$
So for large $w$ values, this is a good approximation:
$$w \pm 1 \approx  -\frac{y}{a}$$
$${cosh}^{-1}\Bigr(\frac{a}{x}\Bigl) \pm 1 \approx  -\frac{y}{a}$$
$${cosh}^{-1}\Bigr(\frac{a}{x}\Bigl)\approx  -\frac{y}{a} \mp 1 $$
$$\frac{a}{x}\approx  cosh\Bigr(-\frac{y}{a} \mp 1\Bigl)$$
$$x \approx  \frac{a}{cosh\Bigr(1 \pm \frac{y}{a}\Bigl)}$$
What are large $w$ values? $w$ is large, if $x$ is small, since:
$$\lim_{w \to \infty}(w \pm tanh(w)) = w \pm 1$$
$$\lim_{{cosh}^{-1}(\frac{a}{x}) \to \infty}\Bigl({cosh}^{-1}\Bigr(\frac{a}{x}\Bigr) \pm tanh\Bigl({cosh}^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{a}{x}\Bigr)\Bigr)\Bigr) = {cosh}^{-1}\Bigr(\frac{a}{x}\Bigr) \pm 1$$
$$\lim_{\frac{a}{x} \to \infty}\Bigl( \pm tanh\Bigl({cosh}^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{a}{x}\Bigr)\Bigr)\Bigr) = \pm 1$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left( \frac{\sqrt{\Bigl(\frac{a}{x}\Bigr)^{2}-1}}{\frac{a}{x}}\right) = 1$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\sqrt{\Bigl(\frac{a}{x}\Bigr)^{2}-1}\right) = \lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)$$
Which is true for all $x \in \mathbb{R}.$

**SUMMARY:** If $x$ is small ($x \approx 0$), then a good approximation is:
$$x_{1,2} \approx  \frac{a}{cosh\Bigl(1 \pm \frac{y}{a}\Bigr)}$$